# "Disguised Conjunction" -- What's going on here?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

I've been reading Brian A. Garner's *The Chicago Guide to Grammar, Usage, and Punctuation* and have been running through the section on conjunctions. I am confused by one of Garner's passages, which I've quoted below.

> **275 Disguised conjunctions.** So-called disguised conjunctions are participles that have been long been used as conjunctions--e.g., *barring, considering, provided, regarding, speaking, and supposing*. A disguised conjunction does not have a subject, while a verb does {**considering** the poor road conditions, we traveled swiftly [considering as a preposition]} {we traveled swiftly, **considering** the poor road conditions [considering as a disguised conjunction]} {the committee **is considering** a budget increase [considering as a verb]}. The key distinction is that a conjunction does not take an object but a preposition does.

1. Specifically, can someone help me understand how "considering" functions as a conjunction in his second example (i.e., "we traveled swiftly, considering the road conditions")?
2. Also, with his example, Garner explains that one distinguishing characteristic of a conjunction (as least as compared to a preposition) is that is doesn't take an object. But then, grammatically, what is the function of "the poor road conditions" in his second example?

Comment: Interesting that participles are used in this place. 'Despite' and 'given' both work in the place of 'considering'.

Comment: If you ask me, those two sentences should be parsed exactly the same- one simply has an inverted form.  But what do I know?

Answer (score 1):

My first reaction is to call that a typo. This would seem a disguised conjunction:
"We traveled swiftly, considering road conditions were poor."
I can also imagine something like:
"We traveled swiftly, if we are considering the poor road conditions." And it takes the place of 'if'. And the 'we' doing the considering are the speaker and the listener, not the 'we' who traveled.

That's the case for all of these: "barring, considering, provided, regarding, speaking, and supposing" The person speaking now is doing all of the barring, considering, supposing, etc., NOT the subject of the other clause.
"It took you long enough to find the place, considering you live here."
"I will go, provided he goes."
Those are the only 2 ways I can think of any of these being used to link clauses, so my honest belief is that all of them are used to mean "if we are..." or "if it is" in the case of provided:

(If we are) barring an earthquake, nothing bad can happen.
(If we are) considering his age, he should not join us.
(If it is) provided that A = B and A =/= C, B =/= C.
(If we are) regarding our previous discussion, I think you are right.
(If we are) speaking of lunch, I'm hungry.
(If we are) supposing he is rich, you should date him.

"Not including," "keeping in mind" and "ignoring" could also fit this description.

Comment: +1 for a valiant attempt to make sense of what Garner is saying, but I don't think your explanation quite holds water: we can't say anything like \*"barring he comes" or \*"speaking she's here".

Comment: @ruakh Agreed. It seems odd to call these conjunctions when "barring", eg, always takes an object, like a preposition. But my "If we are barring" example uses a conjunction, if, and I wonder if that's what he was thinking. I can't think of another way "barring" could be correct in anything like, "Barring an earthquake, nothing bad can happen." It seems like a participial phrase ("Eating lunch, I saw a dog") EXCEPT that the subject of the main clause can't be the subject of the participle, i.e., "Nothing bad" is not doing the barring. An implicit subject is barring something, surely 1st person.

Comment: It could be interpreted as "If we are barring..."  "While we are barring..."  "Since we are barring..." or "As long as we are barring..." - all using conjunctions. I guess I'd say the "barring" "considering" etc. are vestigial verbs left over from withered subordinate clauses.

Incidentally, "assuming" would be another common one.

Answer (score -1):

At the outset the post is commendable for drawing attention to a new horizon of participles functioning as conjunctions. We know not  what ails grammars, conjunctions are rather ignored.
From the extacts it is evident that all the disguised conjunctions ( barring, provided, considering, regarding, speaking and supposing ) are all participles. Like its twin brother, to-infinitive, this non finitive verb form function in a sentence as a noun, or an adjective or an adverb retaining its genetic verbal qualities. This explains why grammatically " poor road conditions " is the object of 
" considering ". It is its direct argument, prepositions have their indirect arguments.
When participles function as adverbs , they can, at times , modify whole of sentences.

- Frankly speaking, you have drawn attention to hether to ignored terrain.

So, " in consideration of poor road conditions" is analogous to " considering poor road  conditions''. Both have objects— as a preposition or a verb should have.

We can render the example sentence complex :

- When we considered road conditions, we travelled swiftly.

In the example in the post, the dual functionality of subordination and conjunction rests with the participle and powered by its object— if there is any – it refers back to the subject in the main clause, it intentionally has dropped.

We may call them  participles with a difference— disguised conjunctions. The unique aspect about these group of participles is that they embody adverbial subordination — the quality lacking in most other participles. For example,

- Breaking the silence in the room, he spoke at last.

Here "breaking" has no adverbial property— disguised subordination.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can see it by alternative ways of saying it.

A different way to express the thought would be "we travelled swiftly because of the poor road conditions".  In that case, 'because' is a conjuction (because 'because' is a conjuntion).

'Considering' is taking a verb, forming a participle (or gerund, I guess), and using it where a conjunction would go.

Comment: *Because of* is a preposition.